# D-Link router WiFi and LAN segment

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking, lan, wired

I have D-Link 2650 router. Some wireless and wired clients connected to it. The problem is there is no interconnection between wireless and wired devices. For instance, when I start webserver on PC connected to wired LAN, WiFi devices cannot access it (other wired devices can). However all devices are in the same subnet: 192.168.1.x. How can I connect WiFi and LAN devices to one network? Or maybe what I should know first (any information with which I can proceed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had 1.0.10 firmware version in D-Link 2650(NSU).
Seemes that client isolation checkbox is broken in this version.
I've updated to 1.0.17 firmware (following instructions on http://ftp.dlink.ru/pub/ADSL/DSL-2650U/Firmware/) and now have wireless and wired clients communicating each other.

Answer (score 3):

Enable **MultiAP Isolation** option looks similar to **Client Isolation**. The former option is available in D-Link 2750.

Answer (score 2):

Check option **Clients isolation** in Wireless -> Basic.

If it turned ON - clients from LAN wil not access Wi-Fi clients and vice versa.

Comment: Great, there is such option, thanks. But, I found this option turned off. 
I've tried to set it on, reboot and try to ping device. Then I've turned it off again and do another ping. In both cases there is no access (Destination Host Unreachable). But I think this is the very option I've looked for.

Comment: Looks like your guess is correct, but this check option is broken. I've solved my issue by updating to 1.0.17 firmware. Thanks for your tip.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off **Enable MultiAP Isolation** and it will solve the issue.

Comment: I don't see anything similar. Do you have the same router model like me?

Answer (score 0):

We need some more info ... do you know if you have ANY connectivity at all?  Not being able to browse a webserver could be caused by lots of things, not necessarily a network problem.

Can you ping one device from the other?  That's the first place to start.  If you can't ping, then it's not a webserver problem... your router MIGHT be configured not to allow connections between the wired and wireless domains, but that's not common.  Are you running the default settings on the router?

Are you 100% certain that you're connecting the wired devices to the correct ports?  (only because I've seen people get the WAN port wrong...)

Comment: Thanks. I mean, webserver is an example. Basicly: I can't ping wireless clients from wired and vise versa (but actually can ping wired <-> wired, wireles <-> wireless).

I can also determine correct IP, because I see wireless clients in LAN clients list, but I can't access it (ping it) anyway.